# How to update an array of observables using interval?

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, rxjs5

I’m trying to build a dashboard for charts using angular 2 and chart.js (via ngcharts). I’d like to have an array of charts that each update via an http request on a custom interval.

Right now I have three separate chart calls that push data to an array. I’m having trouble when it comes to the next iteration - if I push to the array again, I’ll end up with 3 more charts. I’d like the subscribers in the array to update with new data when the interval emits it.

I’m a little confused as to how to correctly structure the component/service/http relationship for my use case.  I feel that I’m close but I’m definitely missing something. How can I get the interval/subscriber relationship to map to the view and update the existing charts on an interval? 
Any help would be great!

Right now:

**Service:**

I’m implementing the interval here:

```
getSingleChartObsinterval(id: number, interval: number) : Observable<Graph> {

return Observable.interval(interval).flatMap(() => this.getSingleChartobs(id));        
}


getSingleChartobs(id: number) : Observable<Graph> {

    return this.jsonp.get(“api location”)
            .map(response => this.extractJsonData(response, id) as Graph)
}
```

extractJsonData is just taking the response and manipulating it to work with the chart JS. It returns a Graph object that has properties that are easy to work with. I don’t have control of the API so I can’t reconfigure the response to include more than one graph.

**The component:**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ChartsModule } from 'ng2-charts/ng2-charts';
import { ChartService } from './chart.service';
import { Graph } from './graph';
import { OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';


@Component({
  selector: 'ab-chart',
  styles: [`
    .chart {
      display: block;
    }
  `],
  templateUrl: 'app/chart.component.html'
})
export class ChartComponent implements OnInit {

    ngOnInit(): void {
      console.log("Chart component init");

      this.getSingleChart(3, 5000);
      this.getSingleChart(5, 4000);
      this.getSingleChart(6, 5000);
    }

    graph: Graph;
    graphs: Graph[] = [];


    constructor(
        private chartService: ChartService
    ) {}


  getSingleChart(id: number, interval: number): void {
     this.chartService.getSingleChartObsinterval(id, interval)
      .subscribe(x => 
       this.graphs.push(x)
      );
}
}
```

**The view:**

```
<div *ngFor="let graph of graphs" class="chart-container">
    <base-chart
        class="chart"
        [datasets]="graph.datasets"
        [labels]="graph.labels"
        [options]="graph.options"
        [chartType]="graph.type">
      </base-chart>
  </div>
```

Comment: Instead of pushing new graph in your array, can't you just replace the existing graphs with new data ? I don't know anything about chart.js, so maybe it's not possible to replace his data and simply wait for angular to render the new chart

Comment: @NoémiSalaün i think that's kind of what I'm asking. Each chart is on a different interval so I'm hoping I can have each item in the array subscribing to changes and updating itself without having to blow away the array. I tried pushing each object as a subscriber to the array but it didnt work. I'm hoping there is a way I can do this without having to search the array for the ID and update the data myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since each graph has its own `id` (I assume its unique) so I'd just change `getSingleChart()` method to update `graphs` object at specific key. Note I changed the `graphs` property from an array to an object:

```
graphs: {[key: number]: Graph} = {};

getSingleChart(id: number, interval: number): void {
  this.chartService.getSingleChartObsinterval(id, interval)
    .subscribe(x => this.graphs[id] = x);
}

get graphIds() {
    return Object.keys(this.graphs);
}
```

Then in the template you need to iterate the array of keys (you can iterate the `graphs` object:

```
<div *ngFor="let id of graphIds" class="chart-container">
    <base-chart
        class="chart"
        [datasets]="graphs[id].datasets"
        [labels]="graphs[id].labels"
        [options]="graphs[id].options"
        [chartType]="graphs[id].type">
    </base-chart>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer. Both of the answers worked, but this is closer to what I had been trying and caused the least amount of change to my existing approach.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a limited amount of charts? If you always have three you could leverage the `combineLatest` operator (if you have more you would have to use some form of recursion I guess).

In your component you could do the following:

```
 this.graphs = this.getSingleChart(3, 5000).combineLatest(
        this.getSingleChart(5, 4000),
        this.getSingleChart(6, 5000),
        (val1, val2, val3) => return [val1, val2, val3])
        //.subscribe((arrayOfVal) => console.log(arrayOfVal);
```

This will return a new array every time one of the charts gets updated. If chart 2 gets a new value, the function (third argument of the combineLatest) will be called with the old value of 1, the new value for 2 and the old value of three.

In your template you could just be using this:

```
 <div *ngFor="let graph of graphs | async" ...>
```

CombineLatest: https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/combinelatest.md

Comment: Actually this won't work like this because `combineLatest()` returns an Observable, not the values returned from the callback. Also this would implicate that you always have to refresh all charts at once.

Comment: It will indeed return an observable. But, that's kind of the point, the observable could be used in the template in that case with the async pipe. And combineLatest will not enforce every chart to be reupdated. Under the covers, this will hold the latest value of all three calls. For example, A1, B1 and C1. If B1 updates to B2, the next value will be A1, B2, C1. See that A and C references did NOT change. So, it does the same as your answer. But more elegantly AFAIAC since you do not need to clean up the subscription afterwards.

Comment: You're right about the `async` I didn't notice that. However, it will have to update all charts at once and not as you describe it because on every change `graphs | async` receives a new array and then it'll destruct and re-create all three `<base-chart>`s elements again. But your solution is definitely easier than mine.

Comment: I would hope that underneath, the base-chart component would check reference :). Or it would loop over the array and have subComponents that have changeDetection strategy set to onPush.

Comment: I wish I could mark both as answers as they both solve the problem in a different approach. The other answer was closer to my existing approach and was the one I went with, but this answer also helped me out with the combineLatest function and further understanding the async pipe. Thanks for this answer.